# How to create an all-inclusive Go environment to meet the requirements set forth: "application must compile on shared server"

Tags: go, deployment, package, shared-hosting

A little backstory:

I am creating my first Go web app for school.  The professor said that I could use Go.  I asked him if I could use the latest version, 1.13, rather than the version installed on the server, 1.10, to leverage the module management feature and the updated errors module.  He did *not* say that I was restricted to 1.10 and even gave me the contact information of the server admin.  I reached out to the server admin with my professor CC'd and he said he doesn't want to update the server's version of Go in the middle of the semester.  He then included instructions on how to download, install, and use whatever version of Go that I need in my home directory.

> Pick your version:
>
> https://golang.org/dl/
>
> Set it up for your own use:
>
> https://golang.org/doc/install

I installed go 1.13 and updated my own envvars to reflect this version and everything works.

Well, the other requirement is that I have to hand my professor my project and that it has to compile on the server.  I am thinking that if I hand him a bundle and give him directions on how to build it, then I've technically met the requirements of the project so far.

My question is, does Go have anything that takes my Go v1.13 environment and packages everything up so that the project can ***compile*** on the target server?  I have only been able to find solutions along the lines of "*just copy the project binary to your production server*" but that doesn't help me.  I need it to *compile* on the production server.  Besides, I tried copying my binary to the production server and it couldn't find my html templates (stored in ./ui/html/ directory) but I guess that will be solved in this discussion or saved for another SO question later.

```
student@universityserver:~$ ./web
INFO    2019/09/22 10:21:52 Starting server on :5089
INFO    2019/09/22 10:23:03 <ipaddress>:63527 - HTTP/1.1 GET /
ERROR   2019/09/22 10:23:03 handlers.go:29: open ./ui/html/home.page.tmpl: no such file or directory
```

The only thing I can think of right now is to basically add everything they need (the go amd64 binary distribution and all modules) and write a script that handles it all (extract go in local folder, export envvars, build, etc.)

> Dear, Professor.
>
> Copy this tarball to your home directory, extract, run `build_my_goapp.sh` script.
>
> Sincerely,
>   Your student

Comment: The language is called "Go", Not "GoLang"

Comment: I would go with the flow by using 1.10.  Vendor dependencies instead of using Go modules.  Use [golang.org/x/errors](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/xerrors) instead of the new 1.13 error features.

Comment: Regarding templates:  The application probably assumes that the current working directory is the directory above `./ui/html/` in the source directory tree.  That directory will not be present if you copy the executable only to another machine.

Comment: I agree with @CeriseLimón. Go 1.10 isn't that old. Just use it. For a university project, you're unlikely to need mods anyway. Vendoring should be just fine.  On the other hand... In my university days, I often made tasks harder than necessary, just for fun, and I learned a lot... so either way, good luck :)

Comment: I will start the back-porting to v1.10 per your advice.  I need to work the paths out for the modules, though.  I need to use sqlite3 module and so far, I'm failing being able to build because of it not being found.  The GOROOT is set system-wide and they may not have the sqlite3 module installed which puts me in a jam.  Maybe I can pass arguments to the `go build` command to look in a local module repo for some modules and the system repo for others?

Comment: If the server has docker it is simple to build using an official docker image containing a specific version of the Go compiler (eg use image "golang:1.13" from DockerHub).

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was that I can supply a `Makefile` that does anything I need it to do.

(It's actually good practice, if not an *expectation*, of a project that is turned in.)

The requirements were that my project needs to compile on the server and that I had to supply a `Makefile`.  Therefore, any downloading, installing, and setting up of a Go environment for my project can be done, as long as everything happens in the user's environment and is not something that needs `sudo` to install correctly.  The server does not have Docker.